# How to best set CSS :root variables dynamically?

Tags: html, css, drupal

I run a Drupal site and I am in need of a way to customize CSS `:root` variables prior to page load. Namely I want to change some default colors to a user selected one. But I also want to change a background image based on the time of day.

I can think of several ways to do this:

1. Attach the root variables in a style tag with some returned HTML
2. Have a CSS file dynamically changed when settings are edited
3. Update root variables with JS

It seems to me that 1 is the way to go, but it also seems a little sloppy. Are there better, standard practices for allowing custom CSS?

Comment: I would go with 1 or 3.  Both can do it the same way, but one would run server-side and the other client-side.  It just depends on what your setup is like and what might be easier.  Personally I'd lean more towards the JS solution since that's just a file that modifies the HTML, simple.